# Stop Automatic creation of MySQL indexes that avoids duplicate entries for a column

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I am using MYSQL as my database and I got the following error shown in my spring boot application.

```
WARN 28881 --- [io-8443-exec-15]o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000

ERROR 28881 --- [io-8443-exec-15] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'Male' for key 'UK1tfeoi1p1w9fg1exiqgw0y5mj'
```

I am getting a input for gender as Male and MySql has automatically created a unique index and because of that, another user can't enter their gender as Male after one person added it. Then I deleted this index and after that, it worked fine. But after some time it again created an index that avoids getting duplicates values for the gender column.

Can anyone help me to stop automaticly creating of indexes that avoids duplicates values?

Comment: MySQL doesn't create unique indexes automatically, it must be in your table creation parameters.

Comment: If it's coming back by itself, maybe you have a cron job that's periodically "fixing" the table.